# Elasticsearch cluster deployment using Kubernetes issue due to DNS Caching

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

We are trying to deploy elasticsearch cluster deployment using kubernetes.On individual pods elasticsearch is running but not forming cluster.When we trouble shoot came to know that individual pods able to communicate using ipaddresses but not hostnames.We deployed using statefulsets and discovery service which uses hostnames.We are suspecting it is due to DNS caching.

We have tried the procedure as mentioned in the following link.But this procedure we could not able implement.

https://medium.com/@manis.eren/elasticsearch-on-kubernetes-master-connection-problem-because-of-jvm-dns-caching-27db53dea1e4

---

This may be due to Elasticsearch runs with a security manager as mentioned in the following link.But how to implement in kuberentes please let us know.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/networkaddress-cache-ttl.html

Comment: The first link contains very detailed solution. Why were you not able to implement it?

Comment: We are using helm-charts in kubernetes.The config map mentioned in the link is not in working.

Comment: you mean you did everything like in article and it did not help or you don't know how to do that?

Comment: We could not implement everything in the link because we stuck at  configmap. It's format is incorrect. We are getting error there.